# Receiver class RibbonLoadBalancerClient does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method ServiceInstance choose

Tags: java, ribbon, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to load balance services but i'm facing the following error (copy & paste from console):

```
 "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance choose(java.lang.String, org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.Request)' of interface org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.ServiceInstanceChooser.\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:97)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)\r\n\tat feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy12/jdk.proxy12.$Proxy206.findProductByCode(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.controller.CartController.getProduct(CartController.java:47)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)\r\n",
```

The application consists on a service, called products.service, which contains a little database to fetch (this application is working good by itself). The purpose is to call it from another Feign Client service, called shoppingcart.service.

The Shopping Cart Service is working good without the load balancing (i mean, when i use both GET endpoints to call the Products Service endpoints), but when i try to implement Ribbon throws the error mentioned before.

I appreciate any suggestion. If any class or code lines are required please ask me.

Greetings!

**Pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jcifu.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>shoppingcart-ms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shoppingcart</name>
    <description>Shopping Cart microservice for Store with Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Product Feign Client (on shoppingcart service):**

```
package com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.client;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.config.FeignConfig;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.model.Product;

@FeignClient(name = "products.service", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface ProductFeignClient {
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts();
    
    @GetMapping("/products/{productCode}")
    public Optional<Product> findProductByCode(@PathVariable Integer productCode);
    
}
```

**CartService (which contains the Feign invocation):**

```
package com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.service;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.client.ProductFeignClient;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.model.Cart;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.model.Product;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.repository.CartRepo;

@FeignClient(name = "products.service")
@Service
public class CartService {
    
    String productsURI = "http://products.service/products/";
    
    @Autowired
    private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer;
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductFeignClient productFeignClient;
        
    @Autowired
    private CartRepo cartRepo;
    
    public Optional<Cart> findCartById(Integer cartId) {
            return cartRepo.findById(cartId);
    }

    public Optional<Product> findProductByCode(Integer productCode) {
        
        ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancer.choose("products.service");     
        instance.getUri();
        
        Optional<Product> product = productFeignClient.findProductByCode(productCode);
        return product;
    }
    
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        List<Product> products = productFeignClient.getAllProducts();
        return products;
    }
```

**CartController:**

```
package com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.client.ProductFeignClient;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.model.Cart;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.model.Product;
import com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.service.CartService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CartController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CartService shoppingService;
    
    @Autowired 
    private ProductFeignClient productFeignClient;

    @GetMapping(value = "/cart/{cartId}")
    public Optional<Cart> findCartById(@PathVariable Integer cartId){
        return shoppingService.findCartById(cartId);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(){
        List<Product> products = productFeignClient.getAllProducts();
        if(products.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(products);
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/product/{productCode}")
    public Optional<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable Integer productCode) {
        
        return productFeignClient.findProductByCode(productCode);
    }
```

**Ribbon Configuration (called LoadBalancerConfig)**

The main purpose of this class is to customize the ribbon load balancing later, so i pre-set some configurations.

```
package com.jcifu.store.shoppingcart.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IPing;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.PingUrl;


public class LoadBalancerConfig {

    @Autowired
    LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient;
    
    @Autowired
    IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig;
    
    @Bean
    public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config) {
        return new PingUrl(false, "/health/products");
    }

    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
    }
}
```

**ShoppingCart Service application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 2222

spring:
  application:
    name: shoppingcart.service
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      uri: http://localhost:8888

  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        enabled: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/shoppingservice?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    database-platform:
    show-sql: true 
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
  main:
    banner-mode: off

eureka:
  client:
    service-url: 
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
      register-with-eureka: true
      fetch-registry: true
  instance:
      hostname: localhost 
      status-page-url-path: /info/shoppingcart
      health-check-url-path: /health/shoppingcart    
         
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
           
products.service:
  ribbon:
    EnableZoneAffinity: true
    EnableZoneExclusive: false
    zoneAffinity:
      minAvailableServers: 1
      maxLoadPerServer: 0.7
      maxBlackOutServesrPercentage: 0.6
```

Comment: Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon is no longer supported and it's recommended to migrate to Spring Cloud LoadBalancer instead.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek How it is about using Feign with newer Spring Cloud? It looks like Feign is depending on Ribbon. Isn't it?

Comment: No, it does not, unless you're using a version that is no longer supported. You might want to take a look at this sample that uses OF with SC LoadBalancer under the hood: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/feign-eureka